# How does Laravel call a method in a controller via Route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I cannot understand how Routing works. I tried to read Illuminate\Routing\Route but cannot grasp, how Laravel calls a method in a controller.

Lets say we have:

```
 Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');
```

I found out that you could call it like this

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    App::call('App\Http\Controllers\WelcomeController@index, []);
});
```

But I cannot read anything near that in the Route.php file.

Comment: you are forgetting about the Router itself.

Comment: @lagbox oh yes! thank you for the tip

Answer (score 3):

With out going into all the details, somethings to look at:

```
Router@dispatch -> dispatchRoute
Router@runRoute
Router@runWithinStack
Route@run
   Route@runController
       ControllerDispatcher@dispatch
   Route@runCallable
```

`Illuminate\Routing\Router` `Illuminate\Routing\Route` `Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher`

This will lead you from dispatching to the actual call on the controller itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you see `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider`  you can find `protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';` and

```
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('web')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
}
```

Which means all your web.php routes, for example `Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');` visit `https:://your-domain/` send action in `App\Http\Controllers\WelcomeController` method `index`

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a beast but in a nutshell you have:

- `index.php` will capture the request and send it through the `Http Kernel`.
- `Http Kernel` will try and dispatch the `Request` to the `Router`.
- The `Router` will then find the applicable `Route` (if there is one), get all of the middleware for the `Route`, pipe the `Request` through them and finally `run` the `Route`.
- This should then return a `Response` which ultimately gets returned in the `index.php` file which will send it on.

**NB**

"Running" the route will get the controller method or closure, resolve any dependencies and then call the closure/method.